# ExecuteSqlRaw() complains invalid SQL statement, but it's not

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-5

I have a call:

```
BackFill = "EXEC SYSDBA.BACKFILL('64907RM9')";

_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(BackFill);
```

I have tried the statement in Oracle SQL Developer, and it works. However, when I try to run it via **ExecuteSqlRaw**(), Oracle complains throws an **ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement**

What did I do wrong?  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I change the SQL statement to below:

```
begin SYSDBA.BACKFILL('64907RM9'); end;
```

Now, I am getting **identifier SYSDBA.BACKFILL must be declared**...but it is.

Comment: Try running `select owner, object_name, object_type from all_objects where object_name='BACKFILL'` and see what it says

Comment: @kfinity I can run the stored procedure on Oracle SQL Developer just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that user SYSDBA doesn't own BACKFILL procedure. If you, by any chance, created it using double quotes and lower/mixed case, you'll have to do that again (i.e. reference it with double quotes and match letter case).

Otherwise, if you're running it connected as another user (not SYSDBA), make sure SYSDBA granted you EXECUTE privilege on it.

Comment: I can run the stored procedure on Oracle Sql developer just fine.

Comment: OK, but - connected as **which** user?

Comment: Ah...my stupidity...thank you!  I keep thinking I was running it as the same user, but I wasn't.... :)